# pipeTransport program can't be found when debugging with vscode and wsl

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried compiling and debugging c++ programs in vscode with wsl, compiling succeeded, but when I tried to press F5 to debug, the error is that the pipe program failed to start. Here is my launch.json.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/home/maxu/projects/helloworld/helloworld.out",
        "args": [""],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "/home/maxu/projects/helloworld/",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "windows": {
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
          "setupCommands": [
            {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
            }
          ]
        },
        "pipeTransport": {
          "pipeCwd": "",
          "pipeProgram": "c:\\windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe",
          "pipeArgs": ["-c"],
          "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
          "/mnt/c": "${env:systemdrive}/",
          "/usr": "C:\\Users\\maxu1\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\usr"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

here is the error message
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahNXN.png)

I tried to modify the parameter "pipeProgram" to "c:\windows\system32\bash.exe", but also failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem as yours except that my pipe program is ssh.exe under c:\windows\system32\openssh.

Here is how I work through it: copy openssh folder to c:\ and add that path to my user path environment variable. You can have a try.

I don't know if the windows system folders are accessible from vscode.